# Chrome fails to open links from external applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, dll

Yesterday I encountered a problem regarding chrome. Whenever I click a link in an external application, obviously Windows tries to open it with the default browser. However, I am getting the following error after clicking the link with Chrome set to the default browser:

> chrome.exe - Application Error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.

This happens regardless whether Chrome was opened or not before clicking the link. The issue only happens with Chrome, Firefox and Edge opens links perfectly.

I've looked into the Event Viewer to maybe find some information about the error. Here are the details about it:

> Faulting application name: chrome.exe, version: 53.0.2785.101, time stamp: 0x57cf9ca3
>   Faulting module name: apphelp.dll, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 
>   0x578999e1
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000003685b
>   Faulting process id: 0x2f24
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d20dd64713176c
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
>   Report Id: 39668e91-ebb5-4fcc-8ec3-03d638835187
>   Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling Chrome
- Running *sfc /scannow* to check system file integrity

I'm running Windows 10 if that matters, the installation is only a few days old.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix it without losing anything.

This is what you do.

Download CCleaner.

Install Said cleaner(You can uninstall when done).

Uninstall chrome.

Continue reading guide from edge.

Open CCleaner and click the Registry option and scan for issues, then clear out all the issues.

Then click Cleaner.
Follow these Images on how to set your settings.If you do this ANY OTHER WAY YOU WILL LOSE YOU PREVIOUS SESSION, SAVED TABS, AND ALL SETTINGS. The idea is to fix chrome without losing our stuff.

[Click to view imge of Windows Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH7VK.png)

Do not have anything extra checked here.

[Click to view image of Application Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRz91.png)

Make sure you have chrome COMPLETELY unchecked. We are trying to clear out things that are INTERFERING with chrome, not chrome itself. Click analyze after NOT checking anything with chrome. After it analyzes and it doesn't have anything you DON'T want to lose, go ahead and click Run Cleaner and wait for it to finish and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is also happening on my system.
The way I found to work-around this is either closing or uninstalling Kaspersky antivirus 2017.